# API connection error, connection aborted, OSError (104,’ECONNRESET’)

Tags: connection, batch-processing, patch, econnreset

I am trying to push large amount of data thru API cal, but after pushing some records I am getting this error:

```
API connection error, connection aborted, OSError (104,’ECONNRESET’)
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-46719e97-4f6f-405f-8c85-b22c56c88578/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    671                 headers=headers,
--> 672                 chunked=chunked,
    673             )
```